# Turn MySQL key pair into concatenated list

Tags: mysql, join, view, subquery, concat-ws

I have 3 tables:

```
businesses ( id, name )
categories ( id, name )
business_categories ( business_id, category_id )
```

The 3rd table is many to many, and there is a `PRIMARY KEY` on that pair.

I am trying to create a view that would be something like:

```
business_name    category_names
Pizza Hut        Restaurants, Pizza, Fast Food
Chipotle         Restaurants, Mexican, Fast Food
```

Here is what I am trying

```
SELECT `businesses`.`name`, CONCAT_WS( ',', (
    SELECT `name`
    FROM `categories`
    JOIN `business_categories`
        ON `categories`.`id` = `business_categories`.`category_id`
    WHERE `business_categories`.`business_id` = `businesses`.`id`
) ) 
FROM  `businesses` 
ORDER BY  `businesses`.`id` ASC
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT
  businesses.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name) AS all_categories
FROM
  businesses
    LEFT JOIN business_categories
      ON businesses.id=business_categories.business_id
    LEFT JOIN categories
      ON business_categories.category_id=categories.id
GROUP BY
  businessess.name
```

Comment: Thanks, `GROUP_CONCAT` is what I was looking for. I ended up using `GROUP_CONCAT( categories.name SEPARATOR ', ' )`